# Pandas: sum a column values progressively

Tags: python, pandas, sum

So, I have a column like:

|  | Some Random Values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | -500 |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 300 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5 | -1330 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 7 | 12 |

I want to do a progressive sum so the results in the next cell will be like summed with your ancestor.
So, the first line will be -500 ('cause no value before it)
The second, 500 (result from -500 + 1000)
The third, 800 (result from -500 + 1000 + 300)
And so on. So the result should be:

|  | Sum of the Some Random Values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | -500 |
| 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 800 |
| 3 | 802 |
| 4 | 810 |
| 5 | -520 |
| 6 | -512 |
| 7 | -500 |

What I tried, didn't work however. Is there any way to do it progressively without explicitly summing up all columns?

Comment: [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)?

Comment: this will do ```df['column_name'].cumsum()```  as @sammy suggested